# In CSS, when adding a new class to a container, elements not inline anymore

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put a grid of images and to define a style for those images I creted a class called "images" like this:

```
[class*="image"] { margin-bottom: 20px; width:100%; border-radius: 6px;}
```

The images are defined the following way:

```
   <section class="row">

    <div class="image col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><img src="images/ap1.jpg" alt="Appart"></div>

    <div class="image col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><img src="images/ap2.jpg" alt="Appart"></div>

    <div class="image col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><img src="images/ap3.jpg" alt="Appart"></div>

    <div class="image col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><img src="images/ap4.jpg" alt="Appart"></div>

    <div class="image col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><img src="images/ap5.jpg" alt="Appart"></div>

    <div class="image col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><img src="images/ap6.jpg" alt="Appart"></div>

    <div class="image col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><img src="images/ap7.jpg" alt="Appart"></div>

    <div class="image col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><img src="images/ap8.jpg" alt="Appart"></div>

  </section>
```

I'm using `col-*` classes to adapted the positioning of the images according to the device it's displayed on (laptop or smartphone etc.)

**Problem:** When I add this image class, the pictures are not placed in grid anymore, but one under each others.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Try removing `width: 100%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of the rule `width:100%;`.

Defining the width in percentage`%`, sets the width for that element in terms of percentage width of the **container**. So a `width:100%` is used when we want only one element on one line inside a container.

In your case the "container" is the `<section>` with the `.row` class. And the children are the `<div>` with the `.image` class.

Most probably, you intended to set the `width` to `auto` which is what the value defaults to, anyways.

*Also on a side note, you might be interested in setting the `border-radius` on the elements **inside** the `col-` elements, rather than setting it on the `col-` elements.*

Answer (score 0):

As you are using grid structure

**why you are using**

```
[class*="image"] { margin-bottom: 20px; width:100%; border-radius: 6px;}
```

Its a wrong way to do this. 
Use classes to assign width. You are breaking the rules of framework.

If you are using framework then follow `col-` structure instead of manually assigning width otherwise create your custom css.